# C# HTML Parse dynamic pattern

Tags: c#, html, parsing, dynamic

```
<td title="AZ BULUTLU"><img id="cp_sayfa_imgHadise3" src="../FILES/imgIcon/99/e_36x36t_png/-28.png" alt="AZ BULUTLU" /></td>
```

I need the " < td title= "AZ BULUTLU" >
this td title is dynamic so sometimes it could be <  td title =" SICAK " > or < td title = "COK BULUTLU ">
how to get this dynamic pattern content..

url = http://www.mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/il-ve-ilceler.aspx?m=BALA#sfB
source code = view-source:http://www.mgm.gov.tr/tahmin/il-ve-ilceler.aspx?m=BALA#sfB

Comment: Please let us know what you've already tried. Could possibly look at HTML agility pack, but it would be helpful to know what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, so my answer may sound just as vague... You could do it using a regular expression such as this `<td title="(.*)">` where this capture group `(.*)` will capture the "dynamic pattern".

Answer (score 0):

You can look into JavaScript / jQuery to dynamically fill in the title of the td element.